# What does this exercise from field theory really tell us?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, motivation

> Let $\phi: F\to K$ be a field homomorphism then there exist a field $L$ containing $F$ and a field homomorphism $\Phi: K \to L$ such that  $\Phi \phi=$ id.

Is the above exercise a particular case of some general construction in ring theory? What does the exercise really want to tell us?

Comment: You mean a field $L$ containing $F$

Comment: Anyone knows how to show this? Seriously interested

Comment: @KennyLau: indeed thanks

Answer (score 3):

The key idea here is that every field homomorphism is injective.

Comment: I don’t really follow your answer. Would you mind elaborating a bit more?

Comment: The exercise is just a convoluted way of asking you to prove that every field homomorphism is injective

Comment: Although I may be wrong but intuitively I feel that the exercise says something more than that. Do you have some direct solution of this in your mind? The solution I thought goes like this: I defined $L= F \cup (K \setminus \phi(F)) $ and then i defined a field structure on L by importing the structure from $K$

Comment: @Dontknowanything yes, that's the solution

Comment: @Kennu Lau: thank you!